# What's wrong with this camel clause

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, caml

Just learning how to use camel and having problems.  I can correctly do two different queries, but when I combine them, I get an error message.  I've looked at the documentation and I still do not get what the problem is.

**Query1:**

```
   var specifier1 = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Requestor_x0020_Name' LookupId='True'/><Value Type='Lookup'>" +
                           "<UserID/></Value></Eq></Where>";
```

**Query2:**

```
   var specifier2 = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Text'>"+currentItemID+"</Value>"+
                           "</Eq></Where>";
```

**Combined query:**

```
   var specifier = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Requestor_x0020_Name' LookupId='True'/><Value Type='Lookup'>" +
                           "<UserID/></Value></Eq><And><Eq>"+
                           "<FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Text'>"+currentItemID+"</Value>"+
                           "</Eq></And></And></Where>";
```

The error I get with the combined query is:

```
Request Failed.One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.
undefined
```

After setting the string I have the following calls.  Maybe it needs to be different when you have AND conditions?  My console.log in my enumerator loop seems to be where things fail.  The error message seems to follow the 6x's: xxxxxx

```
   camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query>"+specifier+"</Query></View>");
   var collListItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
   ctx.load(collListItems);
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
            var enumerator = collListItems.getEnumerator();
            count = collListItems.get_count();
            while(enumerator.moveNext()){
                var item = enumerator.get_current();
                console.log("xxxxxID : " + item.get_id());
            }
            if (count == 0) {
                LockDownCells();
            }
        },
        function(sender,args){
             console.log("xxxxxxRequest Failed."+args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    );
```

Comment: I use U2U CAML Query Builder to help build these types of queries.  It connects to your Sharepoint site so you can build a query piece by piece.

Comment: I tried loading that and for some odd reason, I am not able to connect to our on-prem solution.  It asked for my site name and I was using my own credentials and it was not letting me in.  The server was responding with some sort of forbidden message.  I'm guessing our IT is preventing me access via this mechanism.  Changing this access will not be simple.  State Bureau.  lol

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='ID'/>
            <Value Type='Text'>currentItemID</Value>
         </Eq>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Requestor_x0020_Name' LookupId='True'/><Value Type='Lookup'>
            <UserID/></Value>
         </Eq>
      </And>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

Comment: Ok, that worked, but can someone tell me why.  Does the order of the ANDs matter?

Comment: @SteveHarvancik You have an extra And.  You only need the "outer" And that wraps the two clauses together (and not the And you had between them)

Comment: I purposely put that two set of <And>'s there because the source i googled provided me that syntax.  I guess it's true that not everything is true on the internet.  lol. 
 I thought that syntax was strange and didn't follow standard tags.  Now I know why I thought it was strange.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', retrieveListItems);
function retrieveListItems(){
    var currentItemID=2;     
    var listTitle="CL1017"; 
    var specifier = "<Where><And>"+
                     "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Requestor_x0020_Name' LookupId='True'/><Value Type='Lookup'><UserID/></Value></Eq>"+
                     "<Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Text'>"+currentItemID+"</Value></Eq>"+
                     "</And></Where>";

    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query>"+specifier+"</Query></View>");
    var collListItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    ctx.load(collListItems);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
            var enumerator = collListItems.getEnumerator();
            count = collListItems.get_count();
            while(enumerator.moveNext()){
                var item = enumerator.get_current();
                console.log("xxxxxID : " + item.get_id());
            }
            if (count == 0) {
                //LockDownCells();
            }
        },
        function(sender,args){
             console.log("xxxxxxRequest Failed."+args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    );
}
</script>
```

If you only want to query list item by Item ID, I suggest you use code below, we don't need using CAML Query.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', retrieveListItems);
function retrieveListItems(){
    var itemId=2;    
    var listTitle="CL1017";                          
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);  
    var listItem = list.getItemById(itemId);
    ctx.load(listItem);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
            console.log("xxxxxID : " + listItem.get_id());
        },
        function(sender,args){
             console.log("xxxxxxRequest Failed."+args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    );
}
</script>
```

Comment: I need to know if the current record is mine or not.  The only way is by ID and who created it or the requestor.

Comment: OK, did you try use the code above? About the "And" element in the CAML Query, you can refer to the official link here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/and-element-query